# Android, Read timed auto and soap

Tags: android, web-services, soap, android-ksoap2

Ksoap2 trying to connect to the web service. However, the "read timed out" error getting. I do not know what to do.

Ksoap2 'There is an error too? where is the error

Ksoaps libs version: 3.0.1
Emulator 2.2

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetTableUpdateVersionByTableName";
static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
static final String URL = "https://app.xxx.com/IntSecureFlight/SFInternal.svc";
static final String DOMAIN = "app.xxx.com";
static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IOperationSvc/GetTableUpdateVersionByTableName";
TextView sonuc;
EditText tableName;
String message;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sonuc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tableName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tableName.getText(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            new AsyncTaskClass().execute();

        }
    });

}

class AsyncTaskClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // uzun islem oncesi yapilacaklar
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("tableName", tableName.getText().toString());
        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER12);

        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        soapEnvelope.headerOut = new Element[1];
        soapEnvelope.headerOut[0] = buildAuthHeader();
        try {
            HttpsTransportSE transportSE = new HttpsTransportSE(DOMAIN,
                    443, "/IntSecureFlight/SFInternal.svc", 2000);
            transportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);

            Object result = soapEnvelope.getResponse();

            if (result instanceof SoapFault12) {
                SoapFault12 soapResult = (SoapFault12) result;
                message = soapResult.getLocalizedMessage();
            } else if (result instanceof SoapObject) {
                SoapObject soapResult = (SoapObject) result;
                message = soapResult.getProperty(0).toString();
            }
        } catch (SoapFault12 e) {
            message = e.getMessage();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            message = e.getMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            message = e.getMessage();
        }

        return message;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        sonuc.setText(message);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}

public Element buildAuthHeader() {
    Element h = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "UsernameToken");
    Element username = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "Username");
    username.addChild(Node.TEXT, "genel");
    h.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, username);
    Element pass = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "KurumKod");
    pass.addChild(Node.TEXT, "050");
    h.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, pass);

    return h;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

**HttpTransportSEImpl**

```
public class HttpTransportSEImpl extends HttpTransportSE {



public HttpTransportSEImpl(String url) {
    super(url);
}

@Override
public ServiceConnection getServiceConnection() throws IOException {
    ServiceConnection connection = super.getServiceConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
    return connection;
}
```

}

**AndroidManifest** add  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Answer (score 0):

read timed out error and socket time out errors will come on low internet connections

1. check your internet connection strength
2. or check the server response string, you may mismatch the data-type on reading.

and add permissions to listen **network_state and
access_fine_location**

Comment: have not connect problem. add permissions manifest but the problem continues.

Answer (score 0):

edit your code:

```
HttpsTransportSE transportSE = new HttpsTransportSE(DOMAIN,
                    443, "/IntSecureFlight/SFInternal.svc", 60000);
```

Comment: I tested but the problem continues.